# Getting all the drivers installed on the computer

Tags: c#, .net, windows, driver

Is there a way to get all the drivers (their files) installed on the computer? What I basically need is a set of folders, where each folder is particular driver, containing all the related infs and sys files. So, when I reinstall the OS, I can just install all these drivers and everything works fine.

I'd be grateful for any links or advices.

Operating systems are XP, 2003, Vista, 7 and 2008. Preferably, .NET, but anything else also will do.

I'd like to emphasize, it's not about `select * from Win32_PnPSignedDriver`, it's about getting files.

Comment: Why don't you simply look at the installed devices, because there is often more to installing a driver, then just having the file located in the correct place.  In other words just install the devices manually..

Comment: @Ramhound: what do you mean? I need to get this automated. It's like install clean OS, then run magic app and you have fully functional OS with all the required drivers installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See if these links can help:
[Enumerating All Device Drivers in the System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682619%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
[Device Console (devcon)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541193%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
[Enumerating windows device](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/SimpleSetup.aspx)

Comment: I believe that devcon example is what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about doing this in C# but NirSoft have a tool that might do what you need.

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/driverview.html