# How to check whether a driver is installed?

Tags: c#, .net, openvpn

I am working on a VPN project.. I have a small doubt regarding [TUN/TAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TUN/TAP).

How do I programmatically check/detect if a TUN/TAP driver is installed on a system in C#?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can check if a particular driver is installed by executing a [WQL SelectQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.selectquery%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

```
using System;
using System.Management;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Searching for driver...");

            System.Management.SelectQuery query = new System.Management.SelectQuery("Win32_SystemDriver");
            query.Condition = "Name = 'SomeDriverName'";
            System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
            var drivers = searcher.Get();

            if (drivers.Count > 0) Console.WriteLine("Driver exists.");
            else Console.WriteLine("Driver could not be found.");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

If the above code fails to compile, make sure you add a reference to the `System.Management` assembly.

You may also find these references helpful:

[Getting all drivers installed on a computer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7687301/3155705)

[Get a list of installed drivers | DaniWeb](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/code/217155/get-a-list-of-installed-drivers)

Comment: I have a driver named 'NexusDB V3.09 Driver' installed in my machine but using this way i could not find it in the list. Anything missing from my end?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me - if I uninstall the device (and tick the "Delete Driver" box) it still gets found by this query. Yet, if I plug in the device, the "Devices" list in the settings says "Driver is unavailable" and the device can't be used again until I reinstall the driver again.

Comment: I've also found that the result of a WQL query doesn't always match up with what's expected. I use this to scan for drivers and prompt the user to install if not found, but it frequently returns with no driver found when they are indeed installed meaning that my prompt basically shows every time the software is launched.
Any updates on this that might help?