# Check if driver is uninstalled

Tags: c#, windows-7, windows-10

How do I check in C# whether a device driver is installed/uninstalled?

I took a look at this question: [How to check whether a driver is installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23327660/how-to-check-whether-a-driver-is-installed) which suggests using `Win32_SystemDriver`

However, if I uninstall my driver in the Windows Device Manager, it is still found by this query. The `.sys` file is not deleted from the `C:\Windows\System32\drivers` directory (even though I ticked the box to delete driver files) although it does disappear from the Device Manager.  But the driver is being uninstalled because the device is now unusable, and in the "Bluetooth & other devices" page of the Windows Settings (Windows 10), if I plug in the device it is listed but a message underneath says, "Driver is unavailable". It remains in this state until I reinstall the driver.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_SystemDriver");
var drivers = searcher.Get();

foreach (var driver in drivers)
{
    var deviceName = driver.GetPropertyValue("Name") == null ? "<<NULL>>" : driver.GetPropertyValue("Name").ToString();
    var deviceStatus = driver.GetPropertyValue("Status") == null ? "<<NULL>>" : driver.GetPropertyValue("Status").ToString();

    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1}", deviceName, deviceStatus ));
    Thread.Sleep(50);
}

Console.WriteLine("================");
Console.ReadKey();
```

The `deviceName`gives the correct name of the driver and the `deviceStatus`is "OK" whether the driver is installed or not.

I'm tagging Windows 7 as well because the solution has to work in v7 and v10.

Comment: I don't know what is your device driver but certainly it could be in the Registry. there are some nodes on registry which are responsible to keep vital points of the system (Like Device Derivers). You must search for a GUID and check it on the Registry.